# Buttons on the same line in twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, haml

There are buttons and one button group

```
%button.btn{type: :submit}button1
%button.btn{type: :submit}button2
%button.btn{type: :submit}button3

.btn-group{"data-toggle" => "buttons-radio"}
  %button.btn.btn-primary.active{type: :button}
    button4
  %button.btn.btn-primary.active{type: :button}
    button5
  %button.btn.btn-primary.active{type: :button}
    button6
  %button.btn.btn-primary.active{type: :button}
    button7
```

I want all these 7 buttons to be on the same line. Now they are on the different lines: the 3 first ones on one line and the rest of them on a different line. Even if I add div on and place all them into it, nothing changes.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: can you show a pictorial view or a test page or js fiddle

Comment: picture of the different lines?

Comment: yeah ,btw i can throw a jsfiddle with wat ya need , if that will help ya ?

Comment: Just wrap the first three buttons in a container and set it to "display: inline block". That should probably line it up with the other three in the button group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that using `.btn-group` creates a `<div>` with class `btn-group` - divs are normally block-level elements (unless you've styled them otherwise) and thus take up an entire line to themselves.

Something you can do to get around this is to use a span instead:

```
%span.btn-group{"data-toggle" => "buttons-radio"}
  %button ... etc ...
```

The buttons will still behave as expected - Bootstrap doesn't care whether your button group is a span or div.

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/NVHNv/).